# Moving encrypted home folder to a new hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, home-directory

Recently I bought a new hard drive. I'd like to turn this hard drive into the /home. During original install I set my home directory up as encrypted. At this point I dont know how to move the home folder to the new hard drive. Also I dont know how to get it to automatically mount the encrypted home folder.

UPDATE: I was asked to add sudo fdisk -l to this, hopefully this helps

> Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
>   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x000b8a7d
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1   *        2048   616775679   308386816   83  Linux
>   /dev/sda2       616775680   625141759     4183040   82  Linux swap / Solaris
>
> Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
>   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   Disk identifier: 0x00027ef1
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sdb1            2048  1953523711   976760832   83  Linux

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?